# Visual C++ - Virtual method is not overriden

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, polymorphism, visual-studio-2015

I have two classes:

```
template <class T>
class TArray
{
public:
    TArray& operator =(const TArray &array) { return Copy(array); }
    virtual TArray& Copy(const TArray &array) { ... }
}

class TString : public TArray<TCHAR>
{
public:
    TString& Copy(const TString &string) { ... }
}
```

Classes also have needed constructors.
But method `Copy` in second class does not override method in first class.
Consider this code:

```
TString a = _T("aaa");
TString b;
b = a;
```

In third line program enters assignment operator in `TArray`. In it `this` and `array` are really of type `TString`. But when `Copy` is called, program enters method TArray::Copy, not TString::Copy as I expected. Why?

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 RC, but I'm moving some code from Visual Studio 6.0 project, and I'm pretty sure it has worked in it. Is something changed?

Comment: Tht's the perfect situation to test override. Add it to TString &Copy(..) function and look at compiler complains

Comment: You may look at [Covariance_and_contravariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)).

Comment: OK, you won. I can add assignment operator in `TString` to solve this, but I am curious is there any way to call `TString::Copy` from `TArray`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not overriding anything because the methods have different signatures:

```
TArray& Copy(const TArray &array)
```

vs

```
TString& Copy(const TString &string)
```

Answer (score 1):

The signatures should be same for overriding. In your case,there are two different signatures.

```
TArray& Copy(const TArray &array)
TString& Copy(const TString &string)
```